# How to replace hash url from one to another

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to replace
from: https://www.mywebsite.com/search?updated-max=date
to: https://www.mywebsite.com/blog

Only visibly, because https://www.mywebsite.com/blog does not exist.

Comment: Are you asking about URL re-writing on the server?  It's not really clear what you're asking, given the JavaScript and HTML tags used.

Comment: @David yes, it's a re-write

Comment: This sounds like something you'd do server-side then, not client-side.  It seems like you're looking in the wrong place.